# Copy all the nodes of a child to the parent with spread operator or Object.assign avoid ovewritting the same properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to copy all the nodes of a child node to the parent with spread operator or Object.assign (without using Lodash) and avoid ovewritting the same properties.

I was thinking that it might be easier to push the childArray to the root object but all my tries failed.

```js
const tree = {
  rootonlyinfo: "test",
  morefields: "another",
  comments: [{
      text: "This is comm 1",
      id: "1"
    },
    {
      text: "This is comm 2",
      id: "2"
    }
  ],
  attachments: [{
      text: "This is att 1",
      id: "1"
    },
    {
      text: "This is att 2",
      id: "2"
    }
  ],
  children: [{
    comments: [{
      text: "This is comm 3",
      id: "3"
    }],
    attachments: [{
        text: "This att 3",
        id: "3"
      },
      {
        text: "This att 4",
        id: "4"
      }
    ],
    children: [{
      comments: [{
        text: "This is comm 4",
        id: "4"
      }],
      attachments: [{
        text: "This is att 5",
        id: "5"
      }]
    }]
  }],
  childArray: {
    comments: [{
        text: "This is comm from child 1",
        id: "1"
      },
      {
        text: "This is comm from child 2",
        id: "2"
      }
    ],
    attachments: [{
        text: "This is att from child 1",
        id: "1"
      },
      {
        text: "This is att from child 2",
        id: "2"
      }
    ],
    children: [{
      comments: [{
        text: "This is comm from child 3",
        id: "3"
      }],
      attachments: [{
          text: "This att from child 3",
          id: "3"
        },
        {
          text: "This att from child 4",
          id: "4"
        }
      ],
      children: [{
        comments: [{
          text: "This is comm from child 4",
          id: "4"
        }],
        attachments: [{
          text: "This is att from child 5",
          id: "5"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
};

const mergedTree = [{ ...tree.childArray,
  ...tree
}];
console.log("mergedTree", mergedTree);
```

Code example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sxf2y4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Any ideas?

**expected result:**

```
{
   "rootonlyinfo":"test",
   "morefields":"another",
   "comments":[
      {
         "text":"This is comm 1",
         "id":"1"
      },
      {
         "text":"This is comm 2",
         "id":"2"
      },
      {
         "text":"This is comm from child 1",
         "id":"1"
      },
      {
         "text":"This is comm from child 2",
         "id":"2"
      }
   ],
   "attachments":[
      {
         "text":"This is att 1",
         "id":"1"
      },
      {
         "text":"This is att 2",
         "id":"2"
      },
      {
         "text":"This is att from child 1",
         "id":"1"
      },
      {
         "text":"This is att from child 2",
         "id":"2"
      }
   ],
   "children":[
      {
         "comments":[
            {
               "text":"This is comm 3",
               "id":"3"
            },
            {
               "text":"This is comm from child 3",
               "id":"3"
            }
         ],
         "attachments":[
            {
               "text":"This att 3",
               "id":"3"
            },
            {
               "text":"This att 4",
               "id":"4"
            },
            {
               "text":"This att from child 3",
               "id":"3"
            },
            {
               "text":"This att from child 4",
               "id":"4"
            }
         ],
         "children":[
            {
               "comments":[
                  {
                     "text":"This is comm 4",
                     "id":"4"
                  }
               ],
               "attachments":[
                  {
                     "text":"This is att 5",
                     "id":"5"
                  },
                  {
                     "text":"This is comm from child 4",
                     "id":"4"
                  },
                  {
                     "text":"This is att from child 5",
                     "id":"5"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "childArray":{
      "comments":[
         {
            "text":"This is comm from child 1",
            "id":"1"
         },
         {
            "text":"This is comm from child 2",
            "id":"2"
         }
      ],
      "attachments":[
         {
            "text":"This is att from child 1",
            "id":"1"
         },
         {
            "text":"This is att from child 2",
            "id":"2"
         }
      ],
      "children":[
         {
            "comments":[
               {
                  "text":"This is comm from child 3",
                  "id":"3"
               }
            ],
            "attachments":[
               {
                  "text":"This att from child 3",
                  "id":"3"
               },
               {
                  "text":"This att from child 4",
                  "id":"4"
               }
            ],
            "children":[
               {
                  "comments":[
                     {
                        "text":"This is comm from child 4",
                        "id":"4"
                     }
                  ],
                  "attachments":[
                     {
                        "text":"This is att from child 5",
                        "id":"5"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the result that you want to make?

Comment: @DevMaster Thanks for your intresting. I've edit the post and added the expected result.

Comment: You can't do that. `Object.assign` and object spread are both LWW (Last Write Wins). You will need to write a custom function or use a library function.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is for one level deep you can go further by reducing each node

```js
const tree = {
  rootonlyinfo: "test",
  morefields: "another",
  comments: [
    {
      text: "This is comm 1",
      id: "1",
    },
    {
      text: "This is comm 2",
      id: "2",
    },
  ],
  attachments: [
    {
      text: "This is att 1",
      id: "1",
    },
    {
      text: "This is att 2",
      id: "2",
    },
  ],
  children: [
    {
      comments: [
        {
          text: "This is comm 3",
          id: "3",
        },
      ],
      attachments: [
        {
          text: "This att 3",
          id: "3",
        },
        {
          text: "This att 4",
          id: "4",
        },
      ],
      children: [
        {
          comments: [
            {
              text: "This is comm 4",
              id: "4",
            },
          ],
          attachments: [
            {
              text: "This is att 5",
              id: "5",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  childArray: {
    testing: "i am not in parent",
    comments: [
      {
        text: "This is comm from child 1",
        id: "1",
      },
      {
        text: "This is comm from child 2",
        id: "2",
      },
    ],
    attachments: [
      {
        text: "This is att from child 1",
        id: "1",
      },
      {
        text: "This is att from child 2",
        id: "2",
      },
    ],
    children: [
      {
        comments: [
          {
            text: "This is comm from child 3",
            id: "3",
          },
        ],
        attachments: [
          {
            text: "This att from child 3",
            id: "3",
          },
          {
            text: "This att from child 4",
            id: "4",
          },
        ],
        children: [
          {
            comments: [
              {
                text: "This is comm from child 4",
                id: "4",
              },
            ],
            attachments: [
              {
                text: "This is att from child 5",
                id: "5",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};

let childArray = tree.childArray;
let combinedTree = Object.keys(tree)
  .filter((k) => k !== "childArray")
  .reduce((result, currentKey) => {
   if(Array.isArray(tree[currentKey])){
    result[currentKey] = [
      ...tree[currentKey],
      ...(childArray[currentKey] || []),
    ];
   }
    return result;
  }, {});
  combinedTree = {...tree, ...childArray, ...combinedTree}
console.log(combinedTree);

console.log("=== some Ref will be in the console, because of length just stringify to test the orignal output ====");

console.log(JSON.stringify(combinedTree));
```